How to run Vosk on GPU?
I tried the following code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import json

from vosk import BatchModel, BatchRecognizer, GpuInit
from timeit import default_timer as timer

TOT_SAMPLES = 0

GpuInit()

model = BatchModel("model")

with open(sys.argv[1]) as fn:
    fnames = fn.readlines()
    fds = [open(x.strip(), "rb") for x in fnames]
    uids = [fname.strip().split("/")[-1][:-4] for fname in fnames]
    recs = [BatchRecognizer(model, 16000) for x in fnames]
    results = [""] * len(fnames)

ended = set()

start_time = timer()

while True:

    # Feed in the data
    for i, fd in enumerate(fds):
        if i in ended:
            continue
        data = fd.read(8000)
        if len(data) == 0:
            recs[i].FinishStream()
            ended.add(i)
            continue
        recs[i].AcceptWaveform(data)
        TOT_SAMPLES += len(data)

    # Wait for results from CUDA
    model.Wait()

    # Retrieve and add results
    for i, fd in enumerate(fds):
        res = recs[i].Result()
        if len(res) != 0:
            results[i] = results[i] + " " + json.loads(res)["text"]

    if len(ended) == len(fds):
        break

end_time = timer()

for i, res in enumerate(results):
    print(uids[i], res.strip())

print("Processed %.3f seconds of audio in %.3f seconds (%.3f xRT)"
    % (TOT_SAMPLES / 16000.0 / 2,
    end_time - start_time,
    (TOT_SAMPLES / 16000.0 / 2 / (end_time - start_time))),
    file=sys.stderr)

source: https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/blob/master/python/example/test_gpu_batch.py
but got:
C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\vosk-test\.venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\vosk-test\main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\vosk-test\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    model = BatchModel("vosk-model-en-us-0.42-gigaspeech")
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\vosk-test\.venv\Lib\site-packages\vosk\__init__.py", line 243, in __init__
    raise Exception("Failed to create a model")
Exception: Failed to create a model

Process finished with exit code 1

How to run Vosk on GPU using python?

For me, simply recompiling kaldi and vosk like in the Dockerfile of Vladimir link did the trick, don’t use the gpu fork branch but the main vosk.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
